# The sentence wherein 'Resent' is not 'Resent' - the confusion about a wonder verb

Tags: word-meaning, verbs, word-usage

It really surprised me reading the verb *resent* that I thought and the verb *resent* that a dictionary explained to me!

> [resent](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/resent) (v) - *to feel bitter or angry about something, especially because you feel it is unfair*

But then *resent* also means something *sent* again! Consider this conversation between me and my employee

> I am still waiting for the document, Vicky. ~ But I had sent it to you.
>
> That one was blank and I asked you to ***resend*** it ~ True sir, but then I ***resent*** it on the very next moment.*

When I open any dictionary, *resent* means what I wrote up there, the first thing. But is this use of *resent* means *resent* the way I want in my employee example?

Comment: For what it's worth, *resent* (as in being resentful) and *resent* (as the past tense and past participle of *resend*) are supposed to be pronounced differently.

Comment: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/resend

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/133361/16310

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've discovered a [homograph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homograph), and English has quite a few of them:

> The soldier decided to **desert** in the **desert**.
>   Let's get out of this **wind** so I can **wind** my watch without freezing my fingers.
>   The bear is getting **close**; we'd better **close** the windows.

Usually, context provides enough information to figure out which meaning of the word is intended  – including the placement of objects, articles, and infinitives. For example, *resent* (meaning "to feel bitterness toward") is a transitive verb, and will need an object which usually clears up its meaning.

For example, I think it's fairly obvious which *resent* has which meaning in this sentence:

> I **resent** the accusation that I never **resent** the message.

However, if the context is stripped down too much, the sentence becomes ambiguous, and could be interpreted either way:

> I resent that message.

Then there is this example:

> I **resent** the message that you **resent** to me.

which could mean that the message you *re-sent* to me has hurt my feelings, or it could mean that our mail server is on the fritz, and we keep needing to send everything twice.

Comment: In the few minutes since I answered, I had a very similar thought to what J.R. has just posted. I'm surprised that in the context of a conversation about emails, you didn't understand the 'send/sent' part of the word and had to look in a dictionary, where you found another, unrelated, misleading word.
Certainly there are written sentences which are ambiguous: 'I resent the email we were just discussing'. 
(It happens to native speakers when speaking, too. In one lesson I referred to 'desertification', which I explained as the process by which good land turns to dessert!)

Comment: while most of the homograph examples are two words with same meaning but different forms (verb or noun, noun or adverb and so on), both *resent*s are verbs but mean differently.

Comment: @Maulik - Perhaps so, but _resent_ (to have sent again) as a verb is **always** in the past tense, while _resent_ (to feel bitterness toward) is the base verb, so the _resent_ in _I will resent that tomorrow_ can **never** mean "sent again", nor in _I could never resent that again._ Moreover, it's true that many homographs and homonyms are different parts of speech, but not all off them: _He dropped a bow off the bow of the ship; the tear in my shirt brought a tear to my eye_.

Comment: yes, to my surprise, the verb *resent* becomes *resented* in past tense! That's why I called it a *wonder verb!*

Comment: I had wondered what you meant by "wonder verb." :^)

Comment: Sometimes in similar cases, such as with resign and re-sign, a hyphen is used to distinguish the two different words. Resign means to quit; re-sign means to sign again.

Comment: See also http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/133361/if-you-send-an-email-that-you-already-sent-can-you-say-you-resent-it-same-as

Comment: @CarSmack that's a very good point.

Comment: @J.R., You a language school teacher btw?

Comment: @Pacerier - Officially, I'm not a language teacher – I just play one on the Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 4):

The *resent* in the dictionary definition is a verb all by itself. It has a related noun *resentment*, an adjective *resentful* and an adverb *resentfully*. In all cases, the 're' is unaccented and the 's' is pronounced /z/ - so close to /r'zent/.

The *resent* in the sentence is based on *send/sent*, with a 're-' in front of it to mean 'again', so 'sent again'. The 're' is more accented and the 's' is pronounced /s/ - so close to /ree-sent/.

Dictionaries do not (in fact cannot) include every word derived from another root word when the meaning is clear from the root plus the prefix (or suffix). 'Re' meaning 'again', is a common prefix, and 'send' is a common verb.

Comment: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/retry?q=retry; http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/regain; http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/redo and almost all words with *re-*

Comment: There are lots of lexical words with *re-*, but *re-* affixation is very productive, so you can always make more.

Comment: @snailplane - that's true of many common prefixes. Moreover, language evolves. For a long time, the word _unlike_ had one basic meaning: "different from." Now, thanks to Facebook, it'll be a verb before we know it: _"I had to unlike Joe; he was getting too creepy."_

Comment: @J.R. I think _unliking_ comments/posts is already a verb (at least, insofar as I understand its meaning), but maybe _unliking_ Facebook business/pages will be a verb. Moreover, what about _de-friending_ people vs _un-friending_ them?

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid the confusion by writing the word "re-sent" (with a hyphen) for the meaning of "to send again." This may well have a different etymology than "resent," the angry feeling.

In this [poem,](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/11029/is-it-plagiarism-if-you-use-the-same-or-similar-expression-with-different-meani) I used this technique to different my "key word" from a similar one used in a famous song.

Comment: Does this really answer the question? Seems like the OP wants to know whether _resent_ has the meaning as he defines, rather than an alternate spelling/hyphenation for it.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question.

Comment: @Zhanlong Zheng:It answers the question for the OP as a WRITER. That is, how  can I distinguish between the two when I'm using it. It's true that things are a lot less clear for the OP as a READER. But if we could train people to distinguish the two in their WRITINGS, that would solve the problem overall.